# How can I instantiate and add to a class inside a foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#

I have code that I want to use to log error messages. I made two classes like this to hold the messages:

```
public class HttpStatusErrors
{
    public HttpStatusErrors()
    {
        this.Details = new List<HttpStatusErrorDetails>();
    }
    public string Header { set; get; }
    public IList<HttpStatusErrorDetails> Details { set; get; }
}
public class HttpStatusErrorDetails
{
    public HttpStatusErrorDetails()
    {
        this.Details = new List<string>();
    }
    public string Header { set; get; }
    public IList<string> Details { set; get; }
}
```

I think this is a good way to do this but I am not 100% sure and would welcome any suggestions.

What I would like to do is in the first class to store the `Header` which in my example would be "Validation Messages". Then in the `Detail` object I would like to store another `Header` that showed the entity with the error and finally in the `Details` store the validation errors.

What I am confused on is how should I instantiate the classes. I have done this so far. I think this is correct.  But how can I add the details that I need to add:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    var msg = new HttpStatusErrors();
    msg.Header = "Validation Error";

    foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        var header = string.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            var detail = string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }

    }

}.
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No error but I am not sure how I should instantiate the HttpStatusErrorDetails class and add details to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate collections in `Details` properties. Instantiate new items, and add them to collections in loop:

```
var msg = new HttpStatusErrors();
msg.Header = "Validation Error";
msg.Details = new List<HttpStatusErrorDetails>();

foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
{
    var detail = new HttpStatusErrorDetails()
    detail.Header = String.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);

    detail.Details = new List<string>();
    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
    {
        detail.Details.Add(String.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
    }

    msg.Details.Add(detail);
}
```

Btw you can use LINQ for that:

```
var msg = new HttpStatusErrors();
msg.Header = "Validation Error";
msg.Details =
    ex.EntityValidationErrors
      .Select(eve => new HttpStatusErrorDetails {
                Header = String.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State)
                Details = eve.ValidationErrors
                         .Select(ve => String.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage))
                         .ToList()
       }).ToList();
```

---

Also I like extension methods syntax:

```
 public static HttpStatusErrors ToHttpStatusErrors(
      this DbEntityValidationException ex)
 {
      return new HttpStatusErrors {
          Header = "Validation Error",
          Details = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                      .Select(eve => eve.ToHttpStatusErrorDetails())
                      .ToList()
      };
 }

 public static HttpStatusErrorDetails ToHttpStatusErrorDetails(
      this DbEntityValidationResult eve)
 {
      return new HttpStatusErrorDetails {
        Header = String.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                               eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State),
        Details = eve.ValidationErrors
                     .Select(ve => ve.ToErrorDescription())
                     .ToList()
      };
 }

 public static string ToErrorDescription(
      this DbValidationError ve)
 {
      return String.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                           ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
 }
```

Usage of such methods will be like:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    var msg = ex.ToHttpStatusErrors();
}
```

Comment: beat me by a few seconds. It would be better to explain what was missing in addition to just posting the code changes.

Comment: I like the extension method idea but what would the ToHttpStatusErrorDetails() look like ?

Comment: Thanks - Also where would I put the extension method. I mean what class do you recommend I put it in. SOrry but I'm not too familiar with extension methods but it looks really good.

Comment: @Melina extension methods should be declared in static class. E.g. `public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Thanks very much. I tried this and it's giving a syntax error here: eve.ValidationErrors.ToErrorDescriptions()

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Sorry to bother you with this but I still get some syntax errors. Something missing after "eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State)" and also after "ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage)"  I think the latter just has a "}" that's not needed and needs a semicolon

Comment: @Melina yep, there was missing coma and additional braces. Updated

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Thanks very much. I upvoted and accepted. Wish I could award you more points for your great answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
{
    //New Details Entity
    var errorDetail = new HttpStatusErrorDetails();

    //Fill in Header
    errorDetail.Header = string.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);

    //Fill Add a detail for each validation error
    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
    {
        errorDetail.Details.Add(string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
    }

    //Add Detail to header
    msg.Details.Add(errorDetail);
}
```